# Authorizing an org in VS code runs successfully but does not open any browser

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I have installed my VS code, Salesforce CLI and Extension Park. When I try to authorise an org it gives me the below message but does not redirect to a browser. It says the authorisation ran successfully.

11:19:27.823 sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias test --instanceurl https://login.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername
ended with exit code 0

I have checked the path too. Default browser has been set.
In the command line if I try sfdx, it does not return anything though the folder SFDX is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reinstalled the CLI and it worked.